# how to change menu type of sub-category in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

i'm creating a navigation bar for a website built in mango theme. i have set menu type for my top-category "classic", now i want to set my sub-category in "static-width" menu type. any one know how to do it.  [image]

this screen shoot is of product category whose menu type i have selected classic, i what to change menu-type of the sub-category of product to static width

Answer (score 0):

To be included in the menu (with normal behaviour), the category needs to be flaged as is_anchor. You can find it under the tab "Display settings". If indexing and caching are on, you need to reindex and flush before seeing the result on front.